# PostgreSQL: How to Generate JSON from GROUP BY ROLLUP data

Tags: json, postgresql, rollup

Please I need some help in aggregating a Group By ROLLUP(...) into nested JSON.

My Query (with the result) is as shown below

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT main, sub, subsub, count(*) FROM test 
GROUP BY ROLLUP(main, sub, subsub)
ORDER BY main, sub, subsub;
```

**Result**

```
| main | sub | subsub | count |
| ---- | --- | ------ | ----- |
| c    | c-1 | c-1-1  | 1     |
| c    | c-1 | c-1-2  | 1     |
| c    | c-1 |        | 2     |
| c    |     |        | 2     |
| d    | d-1 | d-1-1  | 1     |
| d    | d-1 |        | 1     |
| d    |     |        | 1     |
|      |     |        | 3     |
```

---

But I will like to have its result in json like below

```
{
  c: {
    'total': 2,
    c-1: {
      'total': 2,
      'c-1-1': 1,
      'c-1-2': 1,
    }
  },

  d: {
    'total': 1,
    'd-1': {
      'total': 1,
      'd-1-1': 1
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried json_build_object and the likes but I couldn't manipulate the ROLLUP data. Any Help is highly appreciated!

Here's a [link to the fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qaYGiVWa2hb5XF8WN6MFbV/0) (PostgreSQL V10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a hierarchical query:

```
with totals as (
    select main, sub, subsub, count(*) 
    from test 
    group by rollup(main, sub, subsub)
    order by main, sub, subsub
)

select jsonb_object_agg(main, sub) as main
from (
    select 
        main, 
        jsonb_object_agg(
            coalesce(sub, 'total'), 
            case when sub is null 
                then subsub->'total' 
                else subsub end
        ) as sub
    from (
        select 
            main, sub, 
            jsonb_object_agg(
                coalesce(subsub, 'total'), count
            ) as subsub
        from totals
        group by main, sub
        having main is not null
        ) s
    group by main
    ) m
where main is not null
```

[db-fiddle.](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aHMjWQrTiS45kwau8A2pjv/0)

The version without cte:

```
select jsonb_object_agg(main, sub) as main
from (
    select 
        main, 
        jsonb_object_agg(
            coalesce(sub, 'total'), 
            case when sub is null 
                then subsub->'total' 
                else subsub end
        ) as sub
    from (
        select 
            main, sub, 
            jsonb_object_agg(
                coalesce(subsub, 'total'), 
                count
            ) as subsub
        from (
            select main, sub, subsub, count(*) 
            from test 
            group by rollup(main, sub, subsub)
            ) subsub
        group by main, sub
        having main is not null
        ) sub
    group by main
    ) main
where main is not null
```

Comment: Thank you soo much! 
May I ask... 
(1) What's the difference between using jsonb_object_agg and json_object_agg? I noticed jsonb... ordered it ascending while json... descending. Is it just that?


(2) I learnt CTEs are optimization fence, is it possible to replicate the above with subquery? for performance sake. What about having the Grouped Data as-is and converting it to nested object with javascript. Will there be any performance benefit? for **millions of rows?**

Pardon me for being curious pls. Thanks for the help! I'm accepting as answer.

Comment: I use only `jsonb` as it is faster than `json` when manipulating and extracting values from more complex structures. Though in this case the difference should not be important. In the updated answer you can find a version without a CTE (may be a bit faster). Converting aggregated data to an object in javascript may be much faster than generating json in Postgres, however there may be some drawbacks in case of a really huge data, as js has to do it in memory (I have no experience in this area though).